# How do I filter by a ForeignKey's db_column field without going through the foreign object in Django

Tags: python, django-models, django-queryset

I have a legacy database with non-django naming conventions. If I have the following (cut down) models:

```
class Registration(models.Model):
    projectId=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)

class Application(models.Model):
    applicationId=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    registration=models.ForeignKey(Registration,db_column='projectId')
```

The `ForeignKey` instance causes a property to be created on `Application` called `registration_id`, but this is neither the correct name for the field (I have a hack to  fix this), nor is it able to be used in a `QuerySet`.

Is there some way of using the id field provided by the ForeignKey on the Application model, rather than having to reference it via Registration?

Ie. I write lots of code like:

```
Application.objects.get(projectId=1234)
```

And don't want to have to write it out as:

```
Application.objects.get(registration__projectId=1234)
```

or even

```
Application.objects.get(registration__pk=1234)
```

I'm slightly surprised that:

```
Application.objects.get(registration_id=1234)
```

doesn't work...

Also note, I tried defining the id column as a field as well as the foreignkey which worked for queryset, but inserts complain of trying to insert into the same column twice:

```
class Application(models.Model):
    ...
    projectId=models.IntegerField()
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
Application.objects.get(registration=1234)
```

Comment: Thanks Wogan, not quite what I want to do (Application.objects.get(projectId=1234)) but probably as close as I can get and something I did not realise I could do.

Answer (score 0):

I think just doing `Application.objects.registration.get(projectId=1234)` should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud, I didn't realise that I do that. However I'm marking the other one as the answer, since I presume that this would return a QuerySet relative to registration. Eg:

Application.objects.registration.filter(projectId__in=[1,2,3]).order_by('applicationId')

would not work? Still very useful to know though!